# Pop up abrir uma vez no dia por usuario em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando meu site, e criei um `popup` básico com `html`, `css3`, `javascript` e gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar o `cookie` do usuário e exibir o `popup` apenas uma vez no meu site, segue a sintaxe abaixo.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function fechar() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    var cor = document.getElementById('cor');
    popup.style.display = "none";
    cor.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: url(https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}
.popup p {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
}
.popup p a {
  position: relative;
  top: 68px;
  left: 178px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
img[alt="fechar"] {
  height: 26px;
  width: 28px;
  position: relative;
  left: 454px;
  top: -14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
    <a href="javascript:fechar()">
      <img src="img/fechar.png" alt="fechar">
    </a>
    <p>Inscreva-se em meu canal do youtube Leonardo Santos link abaixo</p>
    <p><a href="#" target="_blank">clique aqui</a>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um objeto data:

`d = new Date()`

Depois aumentar a data em um dia:

`d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1*24*60*60*1000)`

E finalmente criar um cookie que expira passado um dia:

`document.cookie = "visto=true; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/"`

Para saber se já passou um dia verifique se:
`document.cookie == null`

Para saber mais veja este exemplo [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)